# C# - NReco.PdfGenerator non english character not rendering

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, nreco

I am using NReco.PdfGenerator library to generate pdf from html. It is working fine for english language. I also required to include non-english language(marathi) , in that case not working like as expected. rendering black boxes.

**This is my action method:**

```
public ActionResult Assesment_DownloadResultSummaryData(string htmlContent){
  var htmlToPdf = new HtmlToPdfConverter();
                    var margins = new PageMargins();
                    margins.Bottom = 10; // margins.Left = 5;margins.Right = 5;
                    margins.Top = 10;
                    htmlToPdf.Margins = margins;
                    htmlToPdf.CustomWkHtmlPageArgs = "--enable-smart-shrinking  --encoding <encoding>";
                    htmlToPdf.PageFooterHtml = $@"page <span class=""page""></span> of <span class=""topage""></span><br />";
                    //htmlToPdf.Orientation = NReco.PdfGenerator.PageOrientation.Portrait;
                    htmlToPdf.Zoom = 1.0f;
                    return File(htmlToPdf.GeneratePdf(htmlContent, null), "application/pdf","myFile.pdf");

}
```

I am also tried using

```
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
```

but not working. also put a try on decoding to unicode like this :

```
      byte[] utf8Bytes = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(htmlContent);

       byte[] utf16Bytes = Encoding.Convert(Encoding.UTF8, Encoding.Unicode, utf8Bytes);

htmlContent = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(utf16Bytes);
```

this also not worked for me. 
My html contains characters like विषय,मूल्यांकन प्रकार this . in my pdf its showing as à¤®à¥​à¤²à¥​à¤¯à¤¾à¤‚à¤•à¤¨ à¤¨à¤¿à¤•à¤¾à¤²

**Some part of htmlContent:**

```
   <tbody><tr>
                    <td  colspan="6"><p><b>मुल्यांकन निकाल</b></p></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>

                <td style="width:5%"><h4><b>वर्ग :</b></h4></td>
                <td style="width:10%;text-align:left;"><h4><b>Class 1-A</b></h4></td>
                <td style="width:10%"><h4><b>बॅच :</b></h4></td>
                <td style="width:40%;text-align:left;"><h4><b> 25-07-2017-Class 1-A-General Knowledge-English-1</b></h4></td>
                <td style="width:20%"><h4><b>विद्यार्थ्यांची एकूण संख्या :</b></h4></td>
                <td style="width:10%"><h4><b>18</b></h4></td>
            </tr>
            <tr >
                <td style="width:20%"><h4><b>विषय :</b></h4></td>
                <td style="width:10%;text-align:left;"><h4><b>English</b></h4></td>
                <td style="width:10%"><h4><b>विषय :</b></h4></td>
                <td style="width:30%;text-align:left;"><h4><b>General Knowledge</b></h4></td>
                <td style="width:20%"><h4><b>उपस्थित विद्यार्थी संख्या :</b></h4></td>
                <td style="width:10%"><h4><b>17</b></h4></td>
            </tr>

        </tbody>
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Does the font you're using in the pdf, actually contain the glyphs for the tekst you're trying to put in the pdf?

Comment: its correctly rendering in view.

Comment: It's hard to say something concrete without value of "htmlContent" variable. Possibly wkhtmltopdf fallbacks to  the font that doesn't contain marathi characters.

Comment: is there any way to include those characters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**I am posting this answer because in case any one facing same problem will be 
 get helped:**

I found  a solution for this problem by using [SelectPdf](http://selectpdf.com/html-to-pdf/demo/) insted of NReco .

**some sample code:**

```
public ActionResult ConverToPdf(string htmlContent)
        {
            try
            {

                // instantiate a html to pdf converter object
                HtmlToPdf converter = new HtmlToPdf();
                PdfPageSize pageSize = PdfPageSize.A4;
                PdfPageOrientation pdfOrientation = PdfPageOrientation.Portrait;
                int webPageWidth = 1024;
                // set converter options
                converter.Options.PdfPageSize = pageSize;
                converter.Options.PdfPageOrientation = pdfOrientation;
                converter.Options.WebPageWidth = webPageWidth;
                converter.Options.MarginLeft = 10;
                converter.Options.MarginRight = 10;
                converter.Options.MarginTop = 5;
                converter.Options.MarginBottom = 5;
                //converter.Options.WebPageHeight = webPageHeight;

                // create a new pdf document converting an url
                PdfDocument doc = converter.ConvertHtmlString(htmlContent);

                // save pdf document
                byte[] pdf = doc.Save();

                // close pdf document
                doc.Close();

                // return resulted pdf document
                FileResult fileResult = new FileContentResult(pdf, "application/pdf");
                fileResult.FileDownloadName = "Document.pdf";
                return fileResult;
}
```

Answer (score 8):

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

That command worked for me.